# Cannot load such file zip/zip when running rake test:prepare

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

When trying to prepare my database, I keep getting a `Cannot load such file: zip/zip` error. I have seen this problem on SO but none of the answers worked for me. Does anyone have any ideas?

I'm using Ruby 2.0.0-p247 and Rails 4.0.1

Answer (score 5):

You can add `gem 'zip'` to your Gemfile to solve this problem